# AngularJS vs PHP

Tags: angularjs

I have developed a basic web app using normal client-side code (not using angularjs) and the Laravel framework for the backend. A friend (in the software business) is joining to help me refine it and he questioned me using a PHP framework and instead says he would re-write it using AngularJS.

Is AngularJS capable of full read/write of a database to create a dynamic website? Since AngularJS is a javascript framework, I only understood that to mostly be used for front-end and a project would still need a back-end language like PHP.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes it is a client framework. You can use whatever language you want on the server.

Comment: AngularJS is a pure front end framework. If you want to do something on the backend, you need something else to implement the backend side.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation. I must have misinterpreted his response.

Comment: Very common stack and one I use is laravel powered API with angular js for the client website. There is loads of info out there on how to do this and laravel has some nice helpers to make things easier

Comment: I have used Laravel for a handful of months now and love it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular is a front-end (i.e. browser) framework - it can't run on the server without lots of backflips and hacks, and wouldn't buy you a whole lot anyway.

You could write the back end using node.js to connect to your databases and possibly get Angular running partially on the server to generate your initial pages. This is a technique known as "isomorphic javascript" (among other terms). It's an optimization, but if what you've got works I'd stick with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation. I must have misinterpreted his response.